# Zombie mysql process ? - linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, mysql

I am having the following problem with MySQL and Mint:

- mysql is set to run at startup: `sudo update–rc.d mysql defaults`
- After startup the service is running and I can connect to the database through phpmyadmin, joomla etc.
- Sometime later (maybe several minutes, even hours), I cannot connect to the database anymore. When I run: `ps -e | grep mysq` I get the following:

  `2485 ?        00:00:16 mysqld`

However, running `/etc/init.d/mysql status` I get `* MySQL is stopped.`

- Finally, running `sudo service mysql start`, I get `start: Job is already running: mysql` (restarting the service works fine btw).
- mysql.err and mysql.log files are empty.

So, is the service running or not? Why does this happen (and is always like this)?

I am running Mint 17.1 and MySQL 5.6.